# Firebase Rules - restricting access/attacks

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

Firebase looks great but if I'm going to make a mistake anywhere it will be with getting the rules wrong and leaving unintended access to the data. I would love to see a tool that would check for serious flaws in rule structure. I know there is the simulator but you need to already know what to check for.

Here's my first attempt at rules (in theory it should only allow 'anonymous' users access to their own data and then only as a string of 0-20 length).
Would this rule structure (below) allow anyone to access or interfere another user's data?

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid",
        "mylist": {
          ".validate": "newData.isString() && newData.val().length > 0 && newData.val().length < 20",
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `"$uid === auth.uid"` is the documented way to ensure only the user themselves has access to the data. It's covered pretty well in the [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/user-security#section-variable). Do you have a specific fear about the rule?

Comment: Thanks, thats what i thought, but I can't easily check that I haven't left something open. I really like the Firebase security approach but there's no robust way to check rules against known threats.

Comment: If you have a specific known threat, we can probably figure out a way to test it.